# Making a chart in cshtml that uses logarithmic axes

Tags: razor, charts, logarithm, trendline

I am trying to create a chart that will take the X and Y values and plot them on a chart which is in logarithmic scale.

so far i have:

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("myDB");
var data = db.Query("SELECT yvals, xvals FROM mydata ORDER BY xvals");
var myChart = new Chart(width: 333, height: 222)
    .AddTitle("myChart")
    .AddSeries("Default",
        chartType: "Line",
        xValue: data, xField: "xvals",
        yValues: data, yFields: "yvals")
    .Write();
}
```

So it possible to add the logarithmic axes?

Also, am I able to add a trendline and show the gradient of the trendline?

Any help greatly appreciated.